# How to change the font of the legend in a plot in r

Tags: r

I want to change the font of the labels and axes in the plot to Times New Roman or Times.
[Grafico Boruta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQsFV.png)

```
plot(boruta,  family = "Times", cex.lab = 1.0, xaxt = "n", horiz=1, las=1, xlab="Variables", ylab="Importancia")
legend(x = "topleft", legend = c("Importantes",  "Tentativas", "No importantes"), fill = c("green", "yellow",  "red"))
```

I have already tried this code, but it apparently does not change the font of the letters. Could someone tell me how I can change the legend font and plot axes to Times New Roman or Times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the family before calling `legend`.

```
# Set the font family to "Times" and save defaults in `op`
op <- par(family = "serif")
```